# JPA saveAll() method generates N select statements

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa

I am facing a problem where I perform batch updates in database. The code takes data from another DB process it and store in different one. I have a list of e.g 1000 entities which I want to store. Whene I use JpaRepository.saveAll() method it always generates additional Select for each entity in a list to get database object and the performs update in batch. I think the problem exists because ID is not auto generated one, so whenever .save() method checks if object isNew() it always returns false and the select is performed. Do you know any ways to avoid those selects? It really affects performance because insert of 1000 records takes up to 3/4 minutes.

Record.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name"RECORDS")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Records {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "RECORD_NUMBER")
  private String recordNumber;

  @Column(name = "SYS_ID")
  private String sysId;

  @Column(name = "STATE")
  private String state;

  @Column(name = "PRIORITY")
  private String priority;
}
```

Persist:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void persistRecords(List<Record> records) {
  recordsRepository.saveAll(records);
}
```

SimpleJpaRepository.java

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
  Assert.notNull(entity, "Entity must not be null.");
  if(this.entityInformation.isNew(entity)) { // Always returns false
    this.em.persist(entity);
    return entity;
  } else {
    return this.em.merge(entity); // Merge requires to get existing record from db (additional select for each entity)
  }
}
```

Hibernate Session metrics:

```
150649500 nanoseconds spend acquiring 1 JDBC connection;
0 nanoseconds spend releasing 0 JDBC connection;
16513100 nanoseconds spend preparing 411 JDBC statements;
55596016000 nanoseconds spend executing 409 JDBC statements;
290240700 nanoseconds spend executing 2 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spend performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spend performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spend performing 0 L2C misses;
330942400 nanoseconds spend executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 409 entities and 0 collections);
0 nanoseconds spend executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities of 0 collections);
```

Related problem:
[JPA Batch inserts with non auto generated id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60847540/jpa-batch-inserts-with-non-auto-generated-id)

But the solution won't work because the main problem from this question is to insert only new records while I need to perform updates

Comment: I do autowire service which contains persistRecords method and just service.persistRecord(listOfElements); What might be a problem with this?

Comment: if `List<Record> records` contains detached entities, hibernate needs somehow figure out wether those entities are new or already exist in DB

Comment: Yes, they are detached cause they come from another database. It's a quartz job performing synchronization between 2 databases. Some of the records might be new and does not exists yet and some of them might be just updated

Comment: Can't you try and load the entities first in a single query to get them attached?

Comment: Well, that's what I am thinking about to get list of ids load them from db in a single query update on java side records and then another query to persist those who doesnt exists yet. What do you think of this solution?

Comment: That might work although calling `merge()` might work as well if the entity to merge to is already in the 1st level cache (hence the query).

Comment: How about loading list to get them attached. Is it possible to do that in a single query? I can do findAllById(List<String> ids) but I will get a list which has only existing records and then I need to perform operation on 2 lists (original one and returned from db one).